# Whats is methodLists attribute of the structure objc_class for?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

Looking inside the runtime.h, I found the definition of the structure objc_class.

Among various members, We have this :-

**struct objc_method_list **methodLists**

We definitely need to know what all methods a class has,
But a list of methods should be fine, but why do we have "lists" ?

Why not just one list ?

Also, can anyone specify that, Are methods inherited from superclass part of that list or we get to them via superclass pointer that points to parent class's structure.

Comment: I only peeked at [the source](http://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/objc4/objc4-493.11.tar.gz), but it appears to be an implementation detail (see the comment in [`objc-class.m`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-493.11/runtime/objc-class.m)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose is explained in [objc-class.m](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-493.11/runtime/objc-class.m), as linked by Georg:

> cls->methodLists may be in one of three forms:
>
> 1. NULL: The class has no methods.
> 2. non-NULL, with CLS_NO_METHOD_ARRAY set: cls->methodLists points 
>      to a single method list, which is the class's only method list.
> 3. non-NULL, with CLS_NO_METHOD_ARRAY clear: cls->methodLists points to 
>      an array of method list pointers. The end of the array's block 
>      is set to -1. If the actual number of method lists is smaller 
>      than that, the rest of the array is NULL.
>
> Attaching categories and adding and removing classes may change 
>   the form of the class list. In addition, individual method lists 
>   may be reallocated when fixed up.
>
> Classes are initially read as #1 or #2. If a category is attached 
>   or other methods added, the class is changed to #3. Once in form #3, 
>   the class is never downgraded to #1 or #2, even if methods are removed.
>   Classes added with objc_addClass are initially either #1 or #3.

The short answer is therefore "because of categories." When a category is injected, rather than try to combine its method list with the one existing list, a new entry is simply added to `methodLists`, and set to the list coming from the category. This probably makes category injection faster, since it avoids (potential) large reallocations and copying.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my detail investigation into struct objc_method_list **methodLists : http://blog.csdn.net/jasonblog/article/details/7303618

And in short, methodLists stores SEL-IMP mapping of the instance methods by default. In this situation, it has only one list.

As the name 'methodLists' suggests, it can contain more than one list. If you add a category to a class, the runtime system will insert one more list into methodLists, which points to the method-list of the category.

I tried to answer this question several months ago, but at that time SO discard my answer due to network problem. Now I meet it again :)