# Why Apple uses double pointers for method lists in class-type struct on iOS runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, runtime

I read that on iOS runtime, class becomes struct (so are other oc objects) which is like below:

```
struct objc_class {

    Class isa  OBJC_ISA_AVAILABILITY;

#if !__OBJC2__

    Class super_class                       OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;  

    const char *name                        OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE; 

    long version                            OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;  

    long info                               OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;  

    long instance_size                      OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;  

    struct objc_ivar_list *ivars            OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE; 

    struct objc_method_list **methodLists   OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;  

    struct objc_cache *cache                OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;

    struct objc_protocol_list *protocols    OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;

#endif

} OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
```

In above struct, there is this:

```
struct objc_method_list **methodLists   OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
```

I'm rookie in `C` and I don't quite understand why OC is using pointer to pointer `**` for method list.

Why does it not use just the same structure like cache:

```
struct objc_cache *cache                OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
```

Since cache also contains methods that were used earlier.

I think Apple uses double pointers `**` for `method lists` instead of single one `*` for `cache` or `protocols` for a reason.

And why it's called `methodLists` instead of `methodList`?

I am now comparing `cache`, `protocols` with `methodLists`.

I think Apple uses `**` for method lists instead of `*` for others for a technical reason and I wanna know.

If one pointer `*` is enough for method lists why Apple bothered using double `**`?

Comment: You're looking at a definition for pre ObjC 2 classes.  That spec is quite old by now, as we've had ObjC 2.x for a number of years now (at least 6, IIRC).  In any event, you're asking why Apple (or even NeXT) designed it that way, and that's opinion.  The question doesn't belong on SO.

Comment: My C is rusty, but isn't that how one declares an array of pointers that will be malloc'd?

Comment: @Avi I'm not asking the opinion, I'm asking why I cannot just use a simple linked list `*methodList` like `*protocols` or `*cache`, and why it is `methodLists` instead of `methodList`.

Comment: Unless the one who made that decision posts an answer, the answer is opinion.

Comment: "And the question "why I cannot just use a simple linked list..." is meaningless in this context.  1) even when you use a class, you aren't using that part of the struct, and 2) you wouldn't have a choice anyway.  If you want to do something similar, but in a different way, go ahead.  No one's going to stop you.

Comment: @Avi, I am now comparing `cache`, `protocols` with `methodLists`, I think Apple uses `**` for method lists instead of `*` for others for a technical reason and I wanna know. If one pointer `*` is enough why Apple bothered using double `**`?

Comment: Arrays in C can be viewed as a pointer to the start of the list.  If you want to point to that pointer, you use `**`.  That's it.  Why such indirectness is required and/or desired here should be assumed lost to the mists of time, as the question is not appropriate for SO.

Comment: Actually I found the answer: Why methodLists: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847146/whats-is-methodlists-attribute-of-the-structure-objc-class-for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar question: [Whats is methodLists attribute of the structure objc_class for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847146/whats-is-methodlists-attribute-of-the-structure-objc-class-for)

According to the above post and this [article](http://www.jianshu.com/p/d66d65314add), the reason Apple designed `methodLists` with double pointers (it is the same for `OBJC2.0`) is that, briefly, the structure of double pointers is faster for adding `category` methods into class's method list on runtime.

Since double pointers are for a list of method list, so consider each category has one method list, and when adding one or more categories into class on runtime, instead of adding methods one by one, one can simply add the pointer to category method list to the class `methodLists` which has a pointer to each list/array pointer.

I'm not sure if I explain this clearly enough.